# SQL Server Geometry Intersection Points of Roads

Tags: sql-server, geometry, intersection

I have a table in SQL Server that contains road segments using Geometry data type:
ID (int), Geom (geometry), Name (varchar(150))

I want to create a View that contains points that are the intersection points of the road segments, one point per intersection, with a concatenated column that combines the Names like this "Main St @ George St @ Bob Street".

I've got this working to create distinct intersection point geoms, but I haven't a clue how to aggregate and concatenate the street names for each one:

```
select geometry::STGeomFromText(t2.[g], 26917) as Geom
from
(
    select distinct g
    from
    (
        select r1.[geom].STIntersection(r2.[geom]).ToString() as [g]
        from [Roads] r1 inner join
        [Roads] r2 on 
        r1.[geom].STTouches(r2.[geom]) = 1
        and r1.[ID] <> r2.[ID]
    ) t
) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
              RoadA
            , RoadB
            , '@ ' + RoadA + ' @ ' +RoadB as Intersecion
            , geometry::STGeomFromText(t2.[g], 26917) as Geom
from
(
    select  distinct g
            , RoadA
                , RoadB
    from
    (
        select r1.[Geom].STIntersection(r2.[Geom]).ToString()  as [g]
                , r1.Name as RoadA
                , r2.name as RoadB

        from Roads r1 inner join
        Roads r2 on 
        r1.[Geom].STTouches(r2.[Geom]) = 1
        and r1.[ID] <> r2.[ID]
    ) t
) t2
```

Comment: This is pretty close, thanks.  It actually creates one point for each road segment, so if there are 4 road segments it generates one point for each one (on top of eachother).  Is there any way to have just one point?